# How to add Clear button for views exposed filter?

Tags: 7, views

I created a content type and View with Filter Criteria for my project, when I click the Search it shows the appropriate results.

But there is no option to clear the Search Fields and redirected to previous page (View).

In my requirement I need to keep a [clear/cancel] button with [search] button.

How to add [clear/cancel] button with [search] button in View?

Comment: Yes Drupal 7...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Go to you view and Exposed form style settings. (You can find it right side Advanced settings of the view)

[image]

and check the 'Include reset button' option . You can also change the Reset button label. Find below.

[image]

Comment: The reset button appears only if you have made a choice and submitted the form.
By default the button is not visible